# How can I use next statement within a loop in pry when using pry-byebug

Tags: ruby, pry

I'm using `pry-byebug` and want to write like this:

```
3.times do |i|
  next if i == 2
  p i
end
```

But this fails with a error:

```
[1] pry(main)*   next if i == 2
Error: Cannot find local context. Did you use `binding.pry`?
```

I know `next` is used in pry for step execution, that causes the error.
Is there a way to circumvent the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not yet: https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug/issues/44. Help appreciated... :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I wish I could give you a idea for solution. :(

Comment: You're welcome! Fork the repo and read the code! Maybe you find a solution. :)

Comment: In my opinion, Pry shouldn't hijack the word 'next' as it's used by Ruby. It should use only the alias 'n'.